# iOS: How to debug "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, ios7, xcode5

I'm having trouble with my iOS app.  Here is my ticket against the component in question: https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout/issues/52

But for StackOverflow - my question is more general.  How does one go about debugging something like this?

The only error I get is:

```
2013-12-16 18:23:24.307 3rdRevolution[33315:70b] *** -[CFSet countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1336f850
(lldb)
```

Here is a screenshot of xcode:

[image: cl.ly/SzXL]

I did find that LXReordableCollectionView is involved in the crash by commenting out its usage which solved the crash.  But I still don't know why or how to solve it.  And commenting out code to figure things out doesn't seem like a great approach..

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: A case of a dangling pointer. The instance formerly allocated at 0x1336f850 has been released, hence is not available anymore. Enable zombies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode for more.

Comment: @Till I think the presence of this error message means that he already turned on zombies.

Comment: correct, zombies are on.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint will help you out where you are getting exception or which variable is getting released.

Comment: @philswenson Is this ARC code? If not, the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) can be invaluable in finding issues in non-ARC code.

Answer (score 6):

1. If it's your own custom class, put an NSLog in the dealloc.  If not, subclass the class you're using, override dealloc with `[super dealloc]` and an NSLog.
2. Figure out when the object is being deallocated exactly.
3. Figure out why it's being deallocated then.

Comment: This is a pretty cool answer. How about when your class is something cryptic like: NSISRestrictedToNonNegativeVariable ?

Answer (score 0):

I enabled Zombies in the Scheme Diagnostics and found out which class was causing the error (it was a view controller).

It was releasing an already deallocated instance of the class, which is a weird thing to see in an ARC project so it had me stumped.

Turned out I had overlooked a warning.  I had a method that should have returned a value but wasn't.

Once I corrected that error the crash stopped.